# XML Code is not showing

Tags: java, android

My Styles.xml file is not showing xml code in my android project rather than it is showing some thing else like name and parent name sort of GUI input methods. how can i see the XML code of styles in values

Comment: What IDE do you use? Could you provide some screenshots?

Comment: Try clean and build or refresh or close and open your project. As this is IDE problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it could be a UTF-8 Issue.
rename your xml file copy all the xml code and then open up notepad and paste it in there save it as the original name with the .xml extention. have a try and let me know.